# In javascript, is there a way to put a background image on a div, but make it start from the left?

Tags: javascript, css, image, background-image

I'm writing a thing and I have a nice theme going and I have one div with image on the right, with:

```css
#header {
  background-image: url(https://placeholder.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'></div>
```

but for another div I really want the image to be on the left, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: checkout https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try defining background-position: left.